# Query multiple files from AWS s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a list of file names in the s3 bucket. I need to find out which of these files actually exist in s3 bucket. I was thinking about running a query in aws cli. Something like this:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket my-bucket  --output json --query "Contents[?contains(Key, '23043')]"
```

Is there a way to pass a list of all keys i have instead of having to re-run this query for every key?

Comment: You can speed the operation up by heading each object to see if it exists, but the better option is to use a custom program like a Python script to list all of the objects and see which ones from your set of known objects are still in the bucket.

Comment: let's say, I do not have access to programming environment. The only tool that is available is the CLI

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to pass multiple keys to the aws console?

Comment: There isn't.  The AWS CLI is a fairly thin wrapper around the REST API here, and the JMESPath extension you're using to perform the query here doesn't support a complex query like that.